# file cannot be edited by uri on android 10

Tags: android, file, uri

I have an image editor app.It works well except some specific case on android 10. It uses Intent to select an image to edit. you may modify the image as you want, but when you save it , sometimes my app will crash and return to home screen, and no error message is printed. This case seems occur when you select an image which is app private , i.e , it is not in a public directory. Is there any way to check the uri of that image to check whether it is can be edited or not?

Comment: go your logcat and  select no filters where show only selected filter its show all the logs after  your app crash it help us to find the answer

Comment: Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception that causes the crash. So find out. The logcat is your friend.